# How to write data to pc'disk when debugging an Android program?

Tags: android

im testing an Android program which collects data from sensors and processing it. now I want to check the collected signal that Is stored in an array and display it by matlab, but I dont know to output the data to the computer'disk. 
since the methods I've found on the internet only tell me how to output the data to the sd card or other phone'disk,and actually my program Is going to run on A smart watch, So Is it possible to write the array data to pc'disk directly as txt format just Like the commom java using BufferWriter class?Thanks A lot

Comment: You need to use ADB to copy files out of the device or otherwise use a database rather than writing directly to the filesystem. In other words, there's no direct way to connect an external computer to a device and expose as a separate disk

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for replying. So did you mean I should write the data to the device memory First and then copy it to computer by adb?I dont know if it works on A wear device

Comment: I've never used a Wear device, but ADB should be able to connect to it, I think. If not, as mentioned, you can look at a database like Firebase

Comment: @cricket_007 it did work！I achieved it using adb pull command, thank you for your advice